# SpringIntegration - disable DTD validation

Tags: java, xslt, spring-integration, dtd

is there a way to disable DTD validation in an XSLT transformer through XML configuration?

I have a specific response from a client that i don't want to validate (for business reasons)

Can I do this in Spring Integration?

Thanks in advance,

Carl

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
// stop the network loading of DTD files
factory.setValidating(false);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

(see here [TransformerFactory - avoiding network lookups to verify DTDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966597/transformerfactory-avoiding-network-lookups-to-verify-dtds))

Since we know that `<int-xml:xslt-transformer>`supports `source-factory` and `result-factory`, there will be just need to provide your onw implementation for them, e.g. based on exisiting `DomSourceFactory` and `DomResultFactory`, respectivally, and inject that code there in the constructor.

Of course you can inject `DocumentBuilderFactory` to that `DomSourceFactory` and `DomResultFactory`, but you should write some custom `FactoryBean<DocumentBuilderFactory>` to initialize `DocumentBuilderFactory` in its `getObject()`.